# Bash on Ubuntu on Windows can't use `sudo apt-get install <packagename>`

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was excited to use bash on windows but quickly ran into an issue. I am trying to install build-essential, but I get a dependency issue. Upon trying to resolve with sudo apt-get install -f, I run into another error that doesn't make much sense. I've tried update and upgrade, but that didn't work either. F

```
barzevp@UK-LT-8356:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6-dev : Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
barzevp@UK-LT-8356:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfreetype6 os-prober
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-libc-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed
  linux-libc-dev
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 43 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/767 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,946 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 28660 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-123.172_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-123.172) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-123.172_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to install new version of /usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h': File exists
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Full log of what led to the error in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows terminal is here: 
https://pastebin.com/dq2D2Gtz

Comment: Run "apt-get check" to re-build your cache and try again.

Comment: @RamanSailopal, just tried this, but ultimately it leads to the same error (unmet dependencies, use `apt-get -f install` to resolve, etc.)

Comment: I have this same issue, have you solved this in the mean time?

Comment: yep, solved it by switching to Ubuntu 16.04. Happy days now :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a solution, but I see the root of the problem.  It seems to have to do with case sensitivity on the filesystem.  The package for linux-libc-dev puts two copies of a file in /usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6 with only a difference in case; ip6t_HL.h, and ip6t_hl.h.  After placing ip6t_HL.h, it attempts to rename ip6t_hl.h.dpkg-new to ip6t_hl.h.  The system call to rename the file fails, claiming that ip6t_hl.h already exists

On a "real" linux system, ip6t_HL.h and ip6t_hl.h would clearly be different files.  Under WSL they probably had some strange incompatibilities to work out between NTFS's default case insensitive FS and unix's default case sensitivity.

You can duplicate the problem by hand e.g., with

```
echo hi > foo.H
echo hi > foo.h-new
mv foo.h-new foo.h
```

mv: cannot move 'foo.h-new' to 'foo.h': File exists

strace output:

```
rename("/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h.dpkg-new", "/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_HL.h") = 0
open("/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h.dpkg-new", O_WRONLY) = 10
fsync(10)                               = 0
close(10)                               = 0
rename("/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h.dpkg-new", "/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h") = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
write(2, "dpkg: error processing archive /"..., 199dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-libc-dev_4.4.0-98.121_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to install new version of '/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv6/ip6t_hl.h': File exists
) = 199
```

Comment: Same issue reported superuser.com, https://superuser.com/questions/1238903/cant-install-linux-libc-dev-in-ubuntu-on-windows/1297066#1297066

Comment: I can confirm your analysis (BTW, see my workaround below) but not your example involving `foo.H`. Here is a way how I was able to reproduce the inconsistency in the WSL file system regarding case sensitivity:
`touch a.txt; touch A.txt` yields `touch: cannot touch 'A.txt': Input/output error`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Like @dmattp I found that it this is because, unfortunately, the package contains some (header) files with names that are distinct only by letter case, and that the wonderful WSL file system has an inconsistency regarding case sensitiveness.

Here is a workaround, assuming that the package has name `linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-123.172_amd64.deb`:

```
cd any-temp-dir

apt-get download linux-libc-dev
ar x linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-123.172_amd64.deb
tar xJf data.tar.xz # ignore all erors like ./usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ipt_ttl.h: Cannot open: Input/output error
tar cJf data.tar.xz ./usr
ar rcs linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-123.172_amd64-patched.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.xz 

sudo dpkg -i linux-libc-dev_3.13.0-123.172_amd64-patched.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I hope this helps others with that problem. Unfortunately, I cannot confirm if this resolves the issue as I have moved on from that environment and thus cannot test it.

Comment: Thank @Barzev for your swift reaction.
Meanwhile a colleague of mine has tested my workaround on his WSL Ubuntu 16.04 installation. It works there as well.

Answer (score -1):

It says dependencies aren't being installed, so try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev
```

If that doesn't work try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

This will reinstall `build-essential.` Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: This led to the same chain of errors. Here's the log result: https://pastebin.com/7WXkKByh

Comment: Do sudo apt-get autoremove.. See what pops up.

Comment: Same issue.. `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libc6-dev : Depends: linux-libc-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`